# Chrome ignoring cross-domain cookie expiration

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

On domain 1, I have a form that posts to domain 2

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain2.com/result.php">
```

The script result.php on domain 2 sets a cookie on domain 2 that is supposed to last until the year 2038.

```
setcookie('test', 'val', 2147485540, '/', '.domain2.com', false);
```

The cookie is being stored, but on Chrome, the expiration is set to "When I close my browser" (in other words, 0). On Firefox the expiration is set correctly.

Is there any way around this or is this a Chrome security setting regarding cross-domain posting that I'll just have to live with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the expiration, not the domain. You are using `2147485540` which is equivalent to `Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:45:40` Some browsers have trouble with dates beyond 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038.

This will work:

```
setcookie('test', 'val', gmmktime(3, 14, 7, 1, 19, 2038), '/', '.domain2.com', false);
```

This won't:

```
setcookie('test', 'val', gmmktime(3, 14, 8, 1, 19, 2038), '/', '.domain2.com', false);
```

Comment: Right, thanks! I know about the year 2038 thing but I thought I had set it before 3:14:07. I don't know how it ended up being after that time. Silly oversight on my part.